# Finding all n×n permutation matrices

Tags: algorithms, matrices, linear-programming, permutations

If I have a doubly stochastic matrix, how can I find the set of all basic feasible solutions?

Here's [Wikipedia on doubly stochastic matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix).

Comment: According to the link: "The principal fact about doubly stochastic matrices is the Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem. This states that the set $B_n$  of doubly stochastic matrices of order $n$ is the convex hull of the set of permutation matrices (of order $n$), and furthermore that the vertices (extreme points) of $B_n$  are precisely the permutation matrices."   Since the basic feasible solutions (BFS) are the extreme points, is your question about how to find the set of all permutation matrices?

Comment: Yes, is there an algorithm to do so?

Comment: Would you edit your title and question (and tags) to that effect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don Knuth's Volume 4, Fascicle 2, of *The Art of Computer Programming* has a long section on generating all permutations, including algorithms for doing so.  I found a draft [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww-cs-faculty.stanford.edu%2F~uno%2Ffasc2b.ps.gz&rct=j&q=generating%20all%20permutations%20knuth&ei=AvfFTMm_LouksQPf8-DLDQ&usg=AFQjCNEw5tfBK7QyvtTni9utWTNbPAJbIQ&sig2=rwj1e_RcSsJgDYcSpYNI-w&cad=rja) online.  (*Update*: The link still works, but it is now to a zipped file.  However, Knuth has since published [Volume 4A: Combinatorial Algorithms, Part 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201038048), which includes this material on generating permutations as Section 7.2.1.2. )

Then, going from a permutation to a permutation matrix is fairly straightforward.  For example, suppose you have the permutation 1342 of the numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4.  That can be represented in two-line form as

$$\begin{matrix}1&2&3&4\\1&4&2&3\end{matrix}$$

because the permutation sends 1 to the first position, 2 to the fourth position, etc.

Then the permutation matrix is the matrix with 1's in entries (1,1), (2,4), (3,2), (4,3), and 0's elsewhere; i.e.,

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Nice! This neatly solves a problem I had a few months ago. Actually, if it were not for you, I'd not have known Knuth is writing new volumes of TAOCP. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @J.M.: Would you mind editing the title so that it better reflects what the OP really wanted?  I had the rep to do that until they ended the public beta earlier today. :)

Comment: I aim to please. Better?